# Insert value into Text Widget removing previous Value - Tkinter

Tags: python, text, tkinter

I am using a **backspace** button on Text Widget and i want to remove the last character whenever user click on **backspace** button. I am using this code but it is not removing the previous value.

```
input = entry.get("1.0", 'end-2c')
        entry.insert("1.0",input, END)
```

here i am declaring Text Widget

```
entry = Text(Keyboard_App, width=97, height=8)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show you trying to remove anything. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: yes it is. in the first 2 lines of code i am doing that thing

Comment: firstly removing the last character and saving in input and then putting that string in entry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to delete text, you must explicitly call the `delete` method. Calling `insert` alone will not overwrite existing text -- it inserts, as the name implies. `delete` takes one or two indexes. If just one index is given, it deletes the character immediately after the index. If two, it deletes all characters between the two indexes.

If you want to delete the entire contents of the widget, you can use the indexes `"1.0"` and `"end"`:

```
entry.delete("1.0", "end")
```

To delete just the last character you can use just `"end-2c"`, which means the end index minus two characters (minus one refers to just before the trailing newline, so minus two means the character *before* the trailing newline).

```
entry.delete("end-2c")
```